# copy pasting gif file to then paste it on discord golang

Tags: go, copy, gif

I have a GIF file named "text.gif". When I execute my Go file, I want it to copy "text.gif" to my clipboard. Then, I will press "Control+V" and upload that GIF to Discord.

I tried to use "atotto/clipboard", but I might not have done it correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.